# JQuery Ajax request to http://pastebin.com/raw.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pastebin

I try to make a JQuery ajax request to 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php' and using this code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php',
        data: "i=VJ29uFnk",
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('complete');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert('noh!')
        }
});
```

With this I get a status '404' within xhr but the url I can see in firebug looks correct:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VJ29uFnk

Ideas?

Comment: You should be getting Access Denied due to same-origin policy, not 404

Comment: **NO**, you can't do that. -->http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHR calls are protected under the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

What you can do, however, is call a server side script that bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

You could circumvent the same origin policy by creating a php script that captured the data you want: `example.com/getpage.php?url=pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VJ29uFnK`.

Comment: Can you post an example of this PHP script? Thanks!

Comment: I'll do so if I can find the time, but PHP's [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library is at least one way to do it.